# Visual Studio Code. Как убрать табы перед несколькими строками

Tags: visual-studio-code

Всем привет. На просторах ютуба видел как автор в Visual Studio Code выделяет несколько строк мышью и удаляет табы перед ними. Если подробнее - если выделить несколько строк и нажать TAB, то пробелы добавяться сразу перед всеми строками, как сделать обратный еффект? Delette, Backspace удаляют строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого эффекта необходимо выделить строки и нажать <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.